# Returning a Single Type or List of Type?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, types, return, return-type

So, the gist of the problem is I am programming with GameObjects in Unity. And I want a function that returns three different objects. The main problem that arises is that two of them are lists of GameObjects and the other is just a single GameObject. What is the best way to fix this issue? Here's my current code as it stands.

```
static List<GameObject> zombies;
static List<GameObject> humans;
static GameObject psgObject;

public const int HUMAN = 0;
public const int ZOMBIE = 1;
public const int PSG = 2;

public static object GetObject(int @object)
{
    switch(@object)
    {
        case HUMAN:
            return humans;
        case ZOMBIE:
            return zombies;
        case PSG:
            return psgObject;
        default:
            Debug.Log("GetObject() method error");
            return null;
    }
}
```

The awkward thing about this code is that it requires casting whenever the function is invoked. I tried using dynamic types but the compiler Unity uses doesn't support dynamic typing. What do you recommend in this situation?

Comment: Explain what is `psgObject`.

Comment: @Aybe It's a GameObject that's basically a sphere that the humans chase if they aren't near a zombie.

Comment: Well, the intent of your method is not clear, for what cases you are calling it ? Explain in game-mechanics terms.

Comment: This feels like a design problem rather than an implementation problem, but you could just return a list with your object as the single item.

Comment: @Aybe Basically this is GameManager class where everything is instaniated (humans, zombies, purple sphere of glory). The humans, zombies, and the PSG needs references from each other so the GameManger has a static method getter with int consts for easy retrieval of references. For example the humans need the PSG and the Zombies list to know where the zombies are and to run if they get close and of course the PSG location is needed to know where to find and chase it.

Comment: I join @VPellen on this, I think you should edit your question to clearly explain what you're trying to achieve rather than why does doing X is turns out to be weird. Also, please note that https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ is probably a better place for asking such question.

Comment: @VPellen I'm not a big fan of the single list of object return and probably prefer returning an object and casting instead (what I currently have).

Comment: @Aybe Well, ultimately this is not a gamedev question I feel. It's just wanting to either return a single type or a multiple version of the same type. I never really ran into this kind of situation before. The thing I think I'm trying to ask with this question is this can apply to any type (not just GameObjects) what if in another situation you want an array of strings sometimes or just a single string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply turn your single `GameObject` into a list then you'll have the same return type for everything, i.e.

```
public static List<GameObject> GetObject(int @object)
{
    switch(@object)
    {
        case HUMAN:
            return humans;
        case ZOMBIE:
            return zombies;
        case PSG:
            return new List<GameObject>() { psgObject };
        default:
            Debug.Log("GetObject() method error");
            return null;
    }
}
```

Alternatively change the `psgObject` static variable into a list and return it directly.

PS: From a design perspective it would be much better to have different methods `GetHumans`, `GetZombies`, and `GetPSG` since the caller must already be able to distinguish those. And then the question does not even arise.

Comment: The awkward thing about this method is that every time you want to access the PSG you would have to use its 0'th index right? I'm not sure if this is a much better solution than just casting it once. Also the psg is never going to have multiple elements so conceptually it really doesn't make sense for it to be a list just have it match the return type.

Comment: @Alex Yes; I have edited the answer (see PS section). Would that approach be workable?

Comment: You are just fixing a compilation error rather than really helping out the OP to solve his problem.

Comment: @Aybe; there is no compilation error as I understand it.

Comment: Y'know. Sometimes the simplest solution is the best solution, using multiple getters probably makes the most sense. Maybe what threw me off was the similarity of types, if they were all truly GameObject lists than maybe this would be the best solution, but three getters is probably the solution that makes the most sense.

Comment: @Aybe Returning objects doesn't create a compile error, you just got to do an extra casting step each time. This solution arguably equally awkward in my opinion and my obsession with trying to return everything in one method led to me not realize the painfully obvious solution making a different function for each object.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean a compilation, rather, just hiding a structural problem than really helping you out to fix it.